# Typescript does not consider the 'case' of a switch statement as a typeguard?

Tags: typescript

I have the below (vastly simplified for the purpose of this example) code.

```
type Todo = {
    id: string;
    text: string;
};

type Action =
  | { type: 'DELETE'; payload: string }
  | { type: 'CREATE'; payload: Todo }

  function reducer(state: Todo[], { type, payload }: Action) {
        switch (type) {
            case 'CREATE':
                const trimmedText = payload.text.trim(); // TS Error - Property 'text' does not exist on type 'string'
                return [...state, payload];
            case 'DELETE':
                return state.filter((todo) => todo.id !== payload); // TS still thinks, at this line, that the payload could be either string or Todo
            default:
                throw new Error();
        }
    }
```

Questions

- Why does typescript not recognise that in the case of 'CREATE' that the payload cannot be a string?
- And in the case of 'DELETE' why does Typescript not recognise that the payload must be a string?

Comment: Typescript is not smart enough to type-narrow 2 independent variables, it would have worked if you didn't use destructuring.

Comment: @zerkms You legend mate! I've spent hours trying to figure this out heh. Could you please put that in an answer so I can mark it as the accepted correct solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember it's a typescript limitation at the moment: it cannot narrow types for 2 "independent" variables yet. I cannot find a corresponding github issue at the moment, but I think I seen one.

Nevertheless, to get it working instead directly work with the `action: Action` variable, and don't destructure it.

```
type Action =
  | { type: 'DELETE'; payload: string }
  | { type: 'CREATE'; payload: Todo }

  function reducer(state: Todo[], action: Action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'CREATE':
                // ...
            case 'DELETE':
                // ...
            default:
                throw new Error();
        }
    }
```